# Fit data to different array size

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, data-manipulation

I have two sets of data created by two measuring instruments, each instrument gives a time column and voltage column, while the two sets of data represent the same amount of time (or very close), they are stored in different size arrays as the sampling times are different.
I want to get the scipy.stats.pearsonr coefficients but to do this I need the two data sets to be the same size for this.

How can I scale the size of smaller of the two sets to the size of the larger of the two sets, so that the same data is represented with more data points?

Edit.

Sorry I should have provided an example of the data, I didn't intially because there is a extra data in the files and I thought it would draw attention away from the aspect I was having trouble it.

The file named OOL_Drift.dat contains data which I want to know if it correlates with the temperture readings which is contained in TemperatureChannels.txt and Room_Temperature.txt.
The 1st column on each file is time. 
The 2nd column on OOL_Drift.dat contains the data I want to compare.
The 4th, 8th, 12th, 16th, 20th column in TemperatureChannels.txt contains the data to be compared.

Here are the files
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_viQkcWo4Z2LUlyVG82eWpmUXM&usp=sharing

As I have a lot of samples and the readings do not change very quickly I think it should work.

Thank you to all have given suggestions

Comment: If you are sure that you want to do that, @npielawski has given you an idea on how to. However, I believe that you should really think hard on whether you want to do it all. You said it yourself "the same data is represented with more data points", which is flat out impossible, strictly speaking. If both sampling frequencies are a lot higher than the signal you want to compare, it'll (probably) be fine. But if the data is very noisy or you have turbulent measurements, it's (probably) a bad idea. Maybe you should ask a more specific question (with the data) at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

What you could do though, to get to array of the same length, is to take the shorter and to expand it by interpolation of the information.
You can interpolate the signal (bilinear or even trilinear to have better values) and resample it.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer without some minimum example of what you're doing exactly, but one approach that might work is to do it via `pandas`. If you have the timing of your measurements, you could create two DataFrames with datetime indexes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"data":np.random.rand(6)}, index=pd.date_range("01:00:00","06:00:00", freq="H"))

                    data
2016-06-03 01:00:00 0.436862
2016-06-03 02:00:00 0.171859
2016-06-03 03:00:00 0.273939
2016-06-03 04:00:00 0.949059
2016-06-03 05:00:00 0.434267
2016-06-03 06:00:00 0.212041

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"data2":np.random.rand(3)}, index=pd.date_range("01:00:00","06:00:00", freq="2H"))

                    data2
2016-06-03 01:00:00 0.544233
2016-06-03 03:00:00 0.253989
2016-06-03 05:00:00 0.893227
```

You can then simply join the two on the indexes, which will automatically align those observations that happened at the same time, while filling the "missing" observations in the array which has fewer observations with `NaN`:

```
df1["data2"] = df2.data2

                    data        data2   
2016-06-03 01:00:00 0.436862    0.544233    
2016-06-03 02:00:00 0.171859    NaN 
2016-06-03 03:00:00 0.273939    0.253989    
2016-06-03 04:00:00 0.949059    NaN 
2016-06-03 05:00:00 0.434267    0.893227    
2016-06-03 06:00:00 0.212041    NaN
```

You can then use pandas fairly extensive [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) method to fill these `NaN`s before calculating the correlation coefficient - there's likely to be an interpolation routine in there that makes sense for your application.